# How to connect cisco any connect using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cisco

i am using below code to run cisco any connect but i want to connect cisco with excel vba 
which can get username & password data from active workbook.

```
Sub cisco()

 Dim sconnstring As String
 sconnstring = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"

 Shell sconnstring, vbMaximizedFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Use Appactivate method and sendkeys to complete your code afterwards.

Comment: can you share code for same....

Comment: thanks for your guidance shivange.